# How can I create this button style?

Tags: css, svg

I need to create the button styles in the image below (the one on the right is transparent, not white).

The bottom right corner is obviously the tricky part. It's not just a simple bevel; it's slightly rounded.

The best solution I've come up with is to apply an SVG image mask to a pseudo element positioned to the right of the button and reduce the right padding to compensate. But this approach has its limitations:

- it requires a fixed height button (at least, if I want maintain the aspect ratio of the corner)
- it requires a different SVG for each button size
- I don't see how it can work for the transparent button style

So I'm hoping someone can suggest a different/better approach!

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Here is my current approach - https://codepen.io/peteheaney/pen/jwVEPm

```
$primary: #FAB500;

*, *::after, *::before {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {    
  background-image: none;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.2s;

  &:active,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  &--large {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 24.818px;
    height: 52px;
    line-height: 52px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 24.818px;

    &:after {
            border-top: 2px solid $primary;
            border-bottom: 2px solid $primary;
            background: $primary;
      content: "";
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      bottom: -2px;
      width: 24.818px;
      height: 52px;
      mask: url(http://assets.peteheaney.com.s3.amazonaws.com/button-corner-right.svg) top left / cover;
    }
  }

    &--primary {
        color: #000;
        background-color: $primary;
        border-color: $primary;

        &:active,
        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            background-color: darken($primary, 2%);
            border-color: darken($primary, 2%);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Share the code that you have tried.

Comment: the problem will be getting the rounded corners for the cutout on the bottom right, rest can be created using css. You will have to use SVG or PNG. There is not going to be any issue with the size or transparency as they can be fixed via css. If you can try out the css n paste the code here, then we can edit n fix it for you.

Comment: @Deepak Yadav current code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for the approach I have demonstrated in this pen - https://codepen.io/peteheaney/pen/bRBOMq (compiled CSS version below)

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  background-image: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button:active, .button:hover, .button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button--large {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 16px 0 14px 21px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 21px;
}
.button--large:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -2px;
  width: 21px;
  height: calc(100% - 17px);
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.button--large:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button--primary {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FAB500;
  border-color: #FAB500;
}
.button--primary:before {
  background-color: #FAB500;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button--primary:active:before, .button--primary:hover:before, .button--primary:focus:before {
  background-color: #f0ae00;
  border-color: #f0ae00;
}
.button--primary:after {
  content: url(http://assets.peteheaney.com.s3.amazonaws.com/button-corner-primary-large.svg);
}
.button--primary:active, .button--primary:hover, .button--primary:focus {
  background-color: #f0ae00;
  border-color: #f0ae00;
}
.button--secondary {
  color: #000;
  border-color: #FAB500;
}
.button--secondary:before {
  border: 2px solid #FAB500;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.button--secondary:active:before, .button--secondary:hover:before, .button--secondary:focus:before {
  background-color: #FAB500;
}
.button--secondary:after {
  content: url(http://assets.peteheaney.com.s3.amazonaws.com/button-corner-secondary-large.svg);
}
.button--secondary:active, .button--secondary:hover, .button--secondary:focus {
  background-color: #FAB500;
  border-color: #FAB500;
}
```

```html
<a class="button button--large button--primary" href="">My button</a>

<a class="button button--large button--secondary" href="">My other button</a>
```

Firstly, I divided the right-hand portion into top and bottom (using :before and :after). The top-right pseudo element just has a background color and a top right border radius. This way the top-right portion can have a flexible height, meaning the buttons don't need to have a fixed height. The bottom right pseudo element is essentially an SVG ( using content: url(/path/to/svg.svg) ). This pseudo element always has a fixed width and height, so it maintains its size and aspect ratio regardless of the width/height of the button.

The outline style button is just a variation on the other style, with more borders and less backgrounds.

The only downside to this approach is the need for a different SVG for each button style. But I'm happy with that compromise.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind leaving the corner clickable, you could make the button invisible and just use a background image:

```
button{
    width:x;
    height:y;
    border:none;
    background-color:none
    background-image:url(button_image.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:x y;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

With button_image.png being the image of your button style without text.

Comment: Thanks, but that would require a fixed width/height button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to draw it like this using `before` and `after` :

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  bottom: -6px;
  right: -2px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: white;
}

.button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: block;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 4px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 23px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not a bad idea, but it's not quite right to be honest.

Comment: Well, you can try adjusting it as you need it to be. This is just a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this could possibly be achieved with pure CSS.
However an image or an SVG might be a more efficient way to solve this issue.

```css
.Large{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#FFB300;
  border:none;
  padding:20px 0 20px 30px;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  height:40px;
  font:700 1.5em/40px Arial;
}
.Large::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-30px;
  width:30px;
  height:50px;
  background:#FFB300;
  border-radius:0 10px 0 0;
}
.Large::before{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-30px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border-top: 15px solid #FFB300; 
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;  
  border-left: 15px solid #FFB300;
}
```

```html
<a class="Large">LARGE</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a simple bevel rather than being slightly rounded as required. An image won't work as it would be a fixed size. SVG is the current approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really happy with my result, but here it goes just in case you can make it better.

The different color is just to make it easier to see what is what.

I have focused on solving the transparent one. Once you have it, solving the other is easier.

```css
:root {
  --width: 10px;
  --width2: 14px;
}


.test {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border: var(--width) solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange 0%, orange 70%, transparent 70%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

.test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  right: 29px;
  bottom: -10px;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  border: solid 0px transparent;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-bottom-width: var(--width);
  border-right-color: red;
  border-right-width: var(--width2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}


.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 29px;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  border: solid 0px transparent;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  border-bottom-width: var(--width2);
  border-right-color: red;
  border-right-width: var(--width);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. I requires a fixed width/height button, which is an issue. I'll play around with the idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on Arthur's approach.

If you create the bottom right image (the white corner and the yellow corner border) you are able to position this so it stays to the bottom right and you have the rest of the button to style yourself.

```
 button {
    background-image:url(corner.svg);
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
}
```